# Error while doing GetComponentParts in MEF

Tags: wcf, mef

While doing GetComponentParts I am getting following error, to be specific it reporoduces while i do import in continuous loop while handling multiple messages in my WCF application

> The composition produced a single composition error. The root cause is provided below. Review the CompositionException.Errors property for more detailed information.
>
> 1) The composition failed because it did not complete within '100' iterations. This is most likely caused by a cycle in the dependency graph of a part which is marked with a non-shared creation policy.

One more thing I cant locate **CompositionException.Errors** to find the root cause.

Please suggest what workaround possible, as i am not getting a single thread on the net suggesting any way...

Many Thanks

Comment: Error is clear , you probably have circular dependencies between parts instantiated by MEF, write down structure of your components and you'll find it ( or post your code here)

Comment: It should not be case, as each time new independant object is created, and its working most of the time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is working most of the time, it is probably a threading issue which is corrupting MEF's internal state and causing this error.

When using a CompositionContainer from multiple threads, you need to create it with the isThreadSafe parameter set to true, and avoid calling methods which modify what is available - such as `Compose`, `ComposeParts`, or `AddExportedValue`.

Methods which are safe to call are the GetExport and SatisfyImports methods.

Comment: i would like to try your suggestion